# what is the best practice - a new column or a new table?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a users table, that contains many attributes like email, username, password, phone, etc.

I would like to save a new type of data (integer), let's call it "superpower", but only very few users will have it. the users table contains 10K+ records, while fewer than 10 users will have a superpower (for all others it will be null).

So my question is which of the following options is more correct and better in terms of performance:

1. add another column in the users table called "superpower", which will be null for almost all users
2. have a new table calles users_superpower, which will at most contains 10 records and will map users to superpowers.

some things i have thought about:

a. the first option seems wasteful of space, but it really just an ingeger...

b. the second option will require a left join every time i query the users...

c. will the answer change if "superpower" data was 5 columns, for example?

note: i'm using hibenate and mysql, if it changes the answer

Comment: Either option is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a matter of opinion.  My viewpoint on this follows:

If `superpower` is an attribute of users and you are not in the habit of adding attributes, then you should add it as a column.  10,000*4 additional bytes is not very much overhead.

If `superpower` is just one attribute and you might add others, then I would suggest using JSON or another EAV table to store the value.

If `superpower` is really a new type of user with other attributes and dates and so on, then create another table.  In this table, the primary key can be the `user_id`, making the joins between the tables even more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with just adding a new boolean field in your user entity which keeps track of whether or not that user has superpowers.

Appreciate that adding a new table and linking it requires the creation of a foreign key in your current users table, and this key will be another column taking up space.  So it doesn't really get around avoiding storage.  If you just want a really small column to store whether a user has superpowers, you can use a `boolean` variable, which would map to a MySQL `BIT(1)` column.  Because this is a fixed width column, `NULL` values would still take up a single bit of space, but this not a big storage concern most likely as compared to the rest of your table.